# Change the color of a row based on other column using DT - Shiny - R

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a `data.table` with 3 columns.

```
trial <- matrix(c(3,4,1,2,1,2,4,2,5), ncol=3)
colnames(trial) <- c('value', 'min', 'max')
trial.table <- data.table(trial)
```

Using R (Shiny and DT), I would like to change the font color of the column value based on the min and max range.

I am trying to use this:

```
datatable(trial.table, rownames = FALSE) %>%
formatStyle('value', color = styleInterval(c(trial.table$min,trial.table$max), c('orange', 'green', 'red')))
```

But It gives me back:

```
Error in styleInterval(c(trial.table$min, trial.table$max), c("orange",  : 
  length(cuts) must be equal to length(values) - 1
```

The result should be:

Column "value" with the values: 3 with color green, 4 with color red and 1 with color orange.

It works if instead `c(trial.table$min,trial.table$max)` we use numbers - `c(1,2)`...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to style the first row based on the min and max value in that row, then for the next row you want to style using the min and max values from that row, and so on.

Comment: @Carl Is. The Column "Value" changes the style based on min and max values of correspondent row. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution is use rowCallback instead styleInterval.

```
trial <- matrix(c(3,4,1,2,1,2,4,2,5), ncol=3)
colnames(trial) <- c('value', 'min', 'max')
trial.table <- data.frame(trial)


DT::datatable(trial.table,options = list(rowCallback = JS('
                       function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                       if (parseFloat(aData[1]) < aData[2])
                       $("td:eq(1)", nRow).css("color", "orange");
                       if (parseFloat(aData[1]) <= aData[3] && parseFloat(aData[1]) >= aData[2])
                       $("td:eq(1)", nRow).css("color", "green");
                       if (parseFloat(aData[1]) > aData[3])
                       $("td:eq(1)", nRow).css("color", "red");
                       }')))
```

Comment: Could you maybe add some comments to your answer. E.g. why is there `parseFloat()` around the first variable in the if-statements? What do the JS function arguments represent? Do I understand correctly that `td:eq(1)` refers to the column number == 1. 

- thanks from a non-JS-coder